# How to randomly extract a substring of 200 characters from a fasta file

Tags: bash, text-processing, bioinformatics, random

Is there any Linux command one can use to extract a sequence from a file? For instance, a file contains one million lines, and we want to randomly sample only a sequence of 200 characters  from that file (without considering the header).

For random I mean that every 200 sequence gets the same probability to be chosen and none of the substrings chosen are repetitive.

I am thinking of extracting randomly this sequence of 200 characters from a fasta file like this (without considering the header):

```
>NC_001416.1 Enterobacteria phage lambda, complete genome
GGGCGGCGACCTCGCGGGTTTTCGCTATTTATGAAAATTTTCCGGTTTAAGGCGTTTCCGTTCTTCTTCG
TCATAACTTAATGTTTTTATTTAAAATACCCTCTGAAAAGAAAGGAAACGACAGGTGCTGAAAGCGAGGC
TTTTTGGCCTCTGTCGTTTCCTTTCTCTGTTTTTGTCCGTGGAATGAACAATGGAAGTCAACAAAAAGCA
GCTGGCTGACATTTTCGGTGCGAGTATCCGTACCATTCAGAACTGGCAGGAACAGGGAATGCCCGTTCTG
CGAGGCGGTGGCAAGGGTAATGAGGTGCTTTATGACTCTGCCGCCGTCATAAAATGGTATGCCGAAAGGG
ATGCTGAAATTGAGAACGAAAAGCTGCGCCGGGAGGTTGAAGAACTGCGGCAGGCCAGCGAGGCAGATCT
CCAGCCAGGAACTATTGAGTACGAACGCCATCGACTTACGCGTGCGCAGGCCGACGCACAGGAACTGAAG
AATGCCAGAGACTCCGCTGAAGTGGTGGAAACCGCATTCTGTACTTTCGTGCTGTCGCGGATCGCAGGTG
AAATTGCCAGTATTCTCGACGGGCTCCCCCTGTCGGTGCAGCGGCGTTTTCCGGAACTGGAAAACCGACA
TGTTGATTTCCTGAAACGGGATATCATCAAAGCCATGAACAAAGCAGCCGCGCTGGATGAACTGATACCG
GGGTTGCTGAGTGAATATATCGAACAGTCAGGTTAACAGGCTGCGGCATTTTGTCCGCGCCGGGCTTCGC
TCACTGTTCAGGCCGGAGCCACAGACCGCCGTTGAATGGGCGGATGCTAATTACTATCTCCCGAAAGAAT
CCGCATACCAGGAAGGGCGCTGGGAAACACTGCCCTTTCAGCGGGCCATCATGAATGCGATGGGCAGCGA
CTACATCCGTGAGGTGAATGTGGTGAAGTCTGCCCGTGTCGGTTATTCCAAAATGCTGCTGGGTGTTTAT
GCCTACTTTATAGAGCATAAGCAGCGCAACACCCTTATCTGGTTGCCGACGGATGGTGATGCCGAGAACT
TTATGAAAACCCACGTTGAGCCGACTATTCGTGATATTCCGTCGCTGCTGGCGCTGGCCCCGTGGTATGG
CAAAAAGCACCGGGATAACACGCTCACCATGAAGCGTTTCACTAATGGGCGTGGCTTCTGGTGCCTGGGC
GGTAAAGCGGCAAAAAACTACCGTGAAAAGTCGGTGGATGTGGCGGGTTATGATGAACTTGCTGCTTTTG
ATGATGATATTGAACAGGAAGGCTCTCCGACGTTCCTGGGTGACAAGCGTATTGAAGGCTCGGTCTGGCC
AAAGTCCATCCGTGGCTCCACGCCAAAAGTGAGAGGCACCTGTCAGATTGAGCGTGCAGCCAGTGAATCC
CCGCATTTTATGCGTTTTCATGTTGCCTGCCCGCATTGCGGGGAGGAGCAGTATCTTAAATTTGGCGACA
AAGAGACGCCGTTTGGCCTCAAATGGACGCCGGATGACCCCTCCAGCGTGTTTTATCTCTGCGAGCATAA
TGCCTGCGTCATCCGCCAGCAGGAGCTGGACTTTACTGATGCCCGTTATATCTGCGAAAAGACCGGGATC
```

So I can obtain as an example a sequence subset like this:

```
GCATACCAGGAAGGGCGCTGGGAAACACTGCCCTTTCAGCGGGCCATCATGAATGCGATGGGCAGCGACTACATCCGTGAGGTGAATGTGGTGAAGTCTGCCCGTGTCGGTTATTCCAAAATGCTGCTGGGTGTTTATGCCTACTTTATAGAGCATAAGCAGCGCAACACCCTTATCTGGTTGCCGACGGATGGTGATGC
```

Comment: @thanasisp You are right.  I tried to clarify the text and hopefully makes more sense. 
I want to extract randomly a sequence/subset of 200 characters from a bigger file excluding the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to do multiple fast selections of random 200-character length sequences, it's convenient to save a copy of the fasta file without the newlines (excluding the header also).

```
< file.fasta tail -n+2 | tr -d '\n' > newfile
```

So you will be randomly selecting the start character without hitting any newline character and/or doing any calculations to deal with it. Also I assume that `wc -c < file` (or `wc -m`) and `stat -c "%s" file` give the same result (for usual content, locales etc, check it first), so we use `stat` which returns faster.

For a file with `n` characters, the available choices are `n-200`, we exclude from possible start position the last 200 characters because they can not form a 200-character long string.

`shuf` selects the random number for the range `1,n-200` and a combination of `head` and `tail` with `-c` will extract the string.

```
n=$(stat -c "%s" newfile)
r=$(shuf -i1-"$((n-200+1))" -n1)
< newfile tail -c+"$r" | head -c200
```

You could call it many times to get many different *independent* random selections, that means even the same or overlapping sequences.

If you want your selections to follow other criteria, like not at the same position in file and/or not overlapping, you would have to parse random numbers from the same `shuf` command (with higher `-n` value). Or, for not overlapping, discard any new values closer than 200 to the existing ones.

If you want to select x random *independent* but unique sequences you can start producing random lines, remove duplicates and keep x of them with `head`, for example to get 10 of them:

```
while true; do sh test.sh; printf "\n"; done | awk '!seen[$0]++' | head
```

Comment: Thank you @thanasisp! This seems to work fine :) . Do you have any recommendations if I have more than 1 big sequence per file? For example:

>JQ086372.1 Enterobacteria phage HK446, complete genome
ATGGCAGATAAACGAATCCGTTCCGACAGTTCGGCGGCAGCGGTTCAGGCCATGAAAAATGCAGCTGTGG.... (This is longer)

>LK021129.1 Vibrio anguillarum chromosome 2, strain NB10, complete sequence
TCAACTCATCATGTGGATAAGTTGTGCATGAGCCATGATCATGCTTTAAGAAAGTGTT...(This is longer)

>NC_008816.1 Prochlorococcus marinus str. AS9601, complete sequence
AATAGTTAAACTGTTTAAATAAAGAATTCCACAGTTTCCACAAGAACTACTACTACT...(This is longer)

Comment: each of those are separated by \n :
>JQ086372.1 Enterobacteria phage HK446
ATGGCAGATAAACGAATCC...
 >LK021129.1 Vibrio anguillarum
TCAACTCATCATGTGGATAA...
>NC_008816.1 Prochlorococcus marinus
AATAGTTAAACTGTTTAAAT...

Comment: I have updated with a modified version of the first step for this case. If you have more queries, consider posting new separate questions about them, because the comments section is not designed for this, the answers should be focused to questions, and the questions focused to a complete case. You can also have a [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) on this site. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, thank you again! I will post a new question for further queries

Comment: Thanks again @thanasisp. I have just posted my new query.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622814/how-to-separate-a-sequence-200-length-randomized-from-an-extracted-fasta-into-si
Thank you for your previous help!

Comment: @AndresS I am not sure if you really want `< file.fasta grep -v '^>' | tr -d '\n' > newfile` as this combines sequence into once. That means a random string could contain characters from two sequences. So I rollback last change. In any case, this gets domain specific, about programming & fasta, while people here are making Q-As focused to Unix&Linux. In any case, any query should be focued to Unix&Linux, isolated from the domain.

Comment: @thanasisp, I guess this works with only one fasta per file right? I have a script to save each sequences from a multifasta into separate files. However, Im still trying to figure out how to make a for loop of your scirpt for multiple files in order to obtain as an output only those 200 subtrings per single fasta sequences.

Comment: @Freddy Yes! I see the reason was a trailing newline (I used a newfile created on GUI editor) so actually I was using indirectly (n-1), thus working "correctly". Thanks for the notice.

Comment: When trying to run the first comand I get this error. 
tr: extra operand "lambdas.fa"
When clearing uncompressed repeats only one string can be specified
Try 'tr --help' for more information.

This is how I am trying to run it 
:grep -v '^>' | tr -d '\n'< lambdas.fa > newfilelambdas.fa

Comment: Sorry, I do not include this command into this answer. I have said in previous comment that this grep is not what you need, for domain specific reasons, because you don't want one sequence from many files. Additionally the command you write in the last comment, is not a valid shell command, the frst command before the pipe has no file argument.

Answer (score 1):

`shuf` randomly rearranges the file lines. If you want to randomly sample the characters, use fold to put each character in a line.

```
fold -w 1 file | shuf -n 200 | tr -d '\n'
```

`tr` puts them back in a single line.

If you would like to skip the header:

```
tail -n+2 | fold -w 1 | shuf -n 200 | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: My files are around 1-2G and I was planning to use a server with 250G RAM. And yes, it would be great to have the random chars in a single file. Would you say that suf is truly random? :) Thanks again @Quasimodo

Comment: @AndresS So you will have no problems with memory exhaustion, but when you have unusual large files, always mention it in the question. And please, as requested by Paul_Pedant, do confirm (or deny) that you mean extracting 200 *characters* randomly from the file. Shuf is really random.

Comment: @AndresS I know an algorithm that picks random lines and does not require the whole file in memory at once, only a single record. It does require an accurate line count, so may need to read the file twice. Ask if this is of interest.

Comment: @ Paul_Pedant So for example if my random 200 characters substring is between lines 150-152 would that be a problem? Anyway, yes I am interested in the algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Not very efficient, but this extracts a random substring of 200 bytes length of your sequence:

```bsh
n=200                                             # number of bytes to extract
num_bytes=$(tail -n+2 file | tr -d '\n' | wc -c)  # remove header and newlines, save nr. of bytes
offset=$(shuf -n1 -i0-$(( num_bytes - n )))       # random offset, between 0 and num_bytes - n
tail -n+2 file | tr -d '\n' |                     # remove header and newlines
  dd count="$n" bs=1 skip="$offset" 2>/dev/null   # extract substring
```

We need to know the size of the sequence without header and newlines beforehand, thus two passes on the input file
are needed (or a temporary file).

Comment: using emboss infoseq I obtained a  lenght: 39026 for this specific example. Hope that helps

Comment: Hi @Freddy, I tried to follow your script and I couldnt find the 200 sequence provided in my original file. Do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: You can print the offset with `echo "$offset"` to see how many bytes/chars of the sequence were skipped. This is the start position of the 200 sequence. Or use `grep`, e.g: `grep --color "200_chars_here" <(tail -n+2 file | tr -d '\n')`

Answer (score 0):

I note the file sizes quoted are a million lines, and 1-2GB. Copying the whole data to remove newlines, and reading the whole data to clip it with `head` and `tail`, seems an unnecessary overhead.

An alternative is to determine the file size with:

```
szFn="$( stat --format=%s "${Fn}" )"
```

then generate a sequence of random byte offsets within the file with:

```
shuf --input-range=0-$(( szFn - 1 )) -n "${Count}" | sort -n
```

and iterate those offsets to read the file at the required seek offset:

```
dd status=none bs=1 skip="${Skip}" count="${Lth}" if="${Fn}"
```

This method can retrieve 200 single random characters within a 10.8 GB file on HDD in about 1.5 seconds. (For comparison, `wc -l` reads the file in 2m28s.) The question has been clarified since it first appeared, but this method can retrieve multi-byte sequences also. To deal with newlines etc, it could take some extra bytes and just `tr -d '\n'` and clip those small sections.

Due to the expected file sizes, I checked some arithmetical limits. shuf works up to 64-bit unsigned int, and Bash up to 64-bit signed int, as does dd.

I also ran some stats on shuf: it does self-seed on each run, and appears to have no bias in the generated sequences.

Comment: The reason we have to remove newlines first is to achieve randomness without bias. Or else, when the random character number of `shuf` hits `\n`, the first character following is favored to be the start of the selected sequence, there is bias introduced. This is a bit specific to the domain. actually the initial file is one header and one sequence, which is folded to separated lines.

Comment: @thanasisp That implies that the processing moves on to the byte after the \n, doubling the chance it will be hit. That would not apply if missed probes were just discarded. This is hardly serious statistics -- sampling 200 chars in a GB (or sampling 200 consecutive chars once in a GB) is insignificant. Also, the OP has a follow-on question concerning multiple files, which brings any performance issues into sharp focus.

Comment: The question is about selecting a random sequence, not sampling or selecting unique characters. If you don't remove initially the newlines, more coding is required. Even if you discard any first hit to `\n`, you have to remove an unknown number of newlines on the sequence you get and keep 200 valid characters. I have already presented here how to get many random selections, each one in milliseconds for a few G input.