# How to use a for loop in order to save the output from a script into single files

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, random

I got help subtracting a random 200 sequence from a fasta file like this:

> JQ086372.1 Enterobacteria phage HK446, complete genome
> ATGGCAGATAAACGAATCCGTTCCGACAGTTCGGCGGCAGCGGTTCAGGCCATGAAAAATGCAGCTGTGG
> CTTCTCCCGCTTCAGTCTGCCAATATGGATGTGAAACTCGTCGGAAAAAAAGTGGTTTATCGCTATCAACGCAACAGCGAATACGCCGACTTTTCGCAGAAAGAGATTTTTCACCTTAAAGGCTTCGGATTCACCGGGCTTGTAGGCCTGTC...(this still goes for a lot more A or C or G or T)

using this:

```
< file.fasta tail -n+2 | tr -d '\n' > newfile
```

and this:

```
n=$(stat -c "%s" newfile)
r=$(shuf -i1-"$((n-200+1))" -n1)
< newfile tail -c+"$r" | head -c200
```

And as an output I got:
GTTAAGGGCGCCGTTCTGCTTGTCTTTGCTGACATGTTTGAACACCGGACGGCACAAAGCGAAGTGCAGCTTTATGAGAATGCAGCCGCCGAACGCATGATGTTCATTCATCGCAACTGGCGCGGTAAATCTGAACCTGAGGAGGGCTCCTGATGGAACCTGGACGATTCAGGCACAGGGTAAAAATTCTCACCTTCACG

Now I looking to use a for loop using this script for multiple files ending with .fa and saving each random 200 substrings  output from each file into a new file. This means that If I have 3 .fa files like:
`game.fa`
`sport.fa`
`food.fa`

I will create those 200 random subtrsings from each .fa file and create a new file containing only the 200 substring output:

`game_200_subtring.fa`
`sport_200_substring.fa`
`food_200_substring.fa`

Probably its very basic so thanks in advance

Reference: [How to randomly extract a substring of 200 characters from a fasta file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622425/how-to-randomly-extract-a-substring-of-200-characters-from-a-fasta-file)

Comment: Have you asked on the [bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange site?

Comment: @thanasisp I decided to change the question :) So it could fit in this website

Comment: @glennjackman  Ive just changed the question so it could fit here but I will try to ask on the stackexchange future specific bioinformatic questions. Thank you! :)

Comment: Yes @thanasisp you are right. Thats why I thought was a good idea to separate each sequence into a different file. Its probably not the most efficient but at least it works as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want. I've included usage information inside the script itself. Note: I cannot reliably test the output of this script, as I don't have access to the source files, but it *should* work.

This will simply loop over the '.fa' files in the directory from which the script is executed, and run your provided script on each of them, creating a new file in a subdirectory called 'output' for each.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage:
# Run this script from within the same directory as the .fa files.
# A subdirectory named 'output' will be created, in which every
# input file will have a corresponding output file, prefixed with 'seq.'
mkdir -p ./output
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.fa
do
    nf="./output/seq.$f"
    echo "Copying sequence from '$f' to '$nf'"
    
    < $f tail -n+2 | tr -d '\n' > $nf

    n="$(stat -c "%s" $nf)"

    r="$(shuf -i1-"$((n-200+1))" -n1)"

    < $nf tail -c+"$r" | head -c200
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I noticed that within the output folder the seq.whatever.fa files have the original file and not the 200 randomized outputs :/

Answer (score 1):

Take your existing one-file code and put it into a function:

```bsh
random_sample() {
    local fasta_file=$1
    local n r tmp sample
    tmp=$(mktemp)
    < "$fasta_file" tail -n+2 | tr -d '\n' > "$tmp"
    n=$(stat -c "%s" "$tmp")
    r=$(shuf -i1-"$((n-200+1))" -n1)
    sample=$(tail -c+"$r" < "$tmp" | head -c200)
    rm "$tmp"
    printf "%s\n" "$sample"
}
```

Then you can do

```bsh
for file in *.fa; do
    random_sample "$file" > "${file%.fa}_200_substring.fa"
done
```

---

If the fasta files are not huge, I would not use a tmp file:

```bsh
random_sample() {
    local fasta_file=$1
    local data n r
    data=$(tail -n+2 < "$fasta_file" | tr -d '\n')
    n=${#data}
    r=$(shuf -i1-"$((n-200+1))" -n1)
    tail -c+"$r" <<< "$data" | head -c200
}
```

and if the files are < 32767 bytes

```bsh
random_sample() {
    local fasta_file=$1
    local data
    data=$(tail -n+2 < "$fasta_file" | tr -d '\n')
    echo "${data:($RANDOM % ${#data}):200}"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @glenn jackman! I will check it right now