# Comparison of N identical continuous characters from a set of two files with sequences

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, bioinformatics, file-comparison

I have two files of each with 3 sequences (200 length each) with a header like this:

```
#File1

>1  
TGATTGCATAACCACTTAACATCTTGTTTTATCTAAATAAAATTAAGCATGTTATCTTTTTGGGGCACTCCTGGGGCAGTAGATGCCAGTTGTTGATTCAGTATATCTACTTGTGACTGGTTATTATCCCGATTTTTTTAGTTTTAAGGTGTTGACATAGCCATCCATGCTCCATATACTGTATAGACCATCTGAGCGTT  
>2  
TGGGAAAACAGCATTCAGCGGTGGCTTATTCCTGCTAAGGATGTTGGCCGCATTCATGCTGAGCACAACCTCGACGGCCTGCTGAGGGGCGATTCGGCATCCCGCGCTGCCTTTATGAAGGCAATGGGAGAGGCAGGGCTACGCACCATCAACGAGATGCGACGAACGGACAACCTCCCGCCATTGCCGGGTGGCGATGT  
>3  
GAAATGGGAACCGCGAACATGCCTGCACATCCGTTTGTGCGACCCGCTTACGATACTCGCGAGGAAGAGGCCGCCAGCGTCGCCATTGCCAGGATGAATCAGGCTATTGATGAGGTATTGAGCAAGTGAATGAAGATAATATCTACGCCTTGCTTTCTCCCCTGGCAGAAGGACGGGTATATCCCTATGTTGCGCCATTA
```

```
#File2

>1  
TGATTGCATAACCACTTAACATCTTGTTTTATCTAAATAAAATTAAGCATGTTATCTTTTTGGGGCACTCCTGGGGCAGTAGATGCCAGTTGTTGATTCAGTATATCTACTTGTGACTGGTTATTATCCCGATTTTTTTAGTTTTAAGGTGTTGACATAGCCATCCATGCGGGAAGGTGCAGCATAATGTGCTTTGGATT  
>2  
TGAGTGCCCCATTTGTGAAGCAATAAAGTTCGGGTTCGCGCCAGCGGCAAGCGCCCAGCATGCACCGATTTTTTTAGTTTTAAGGTGTTGACATTAGGTATGTCGGGACTGGTATGCTTTCCTGTGTCGCAGCCCGGCGCGTCTCAATGCAGATTCCCATATCCTGTTCATCCATATACTGTATAGACCATCTGAGCGTT  
>3  
TACCTGAGCGATCGGTAATTTGCGGATTGAAGACAAAGGTGCAGGAATGAGTTTTTGTACGACCGTATTCGCGCAGCTTTACTTCAATTTTGTGCTGTTTGCTCAGCTTCGTGAAAGAGGCCTGACTTTTTAAAGCATCAATTGCTGGCTGCACAAGATGTATCACCCTGTCGGTTCCTGCCTGGGTTTTCGGCAGGGTG
```

I would like to compare each sequence from file1 vs file2 (without considering the headers) (File1: 1,2,3 vs File2: 1,2,3) and if **exactly 30 continuous characters were identical** from both sequences, I would like to save the headers of the sequences having a match (only those with a match) in an outputfile.

For example the 30 characters string:

`TGATTGCATAACCACTTAACATCTTGTTTT` is present in seq1 from file1 and seq1 from file2.
`TCCATATACTGTATAGACCATCTGAGCGTT` is present in seq1 from file1 and seq2 from file2.

so I will end up with an output file like:

```
[1,1]  
[1,2]  
...
```

Comment: Didn't we have this same question or something very like it, just last week?

Comment: @roaima are you thinking of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/622425/117549?

Comment: @JeffSchaller ah, yes, thank you. And https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/622968/100397. As has been said elsewhere, variations on a theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { wid = 30 }
sub(/^>/,"") { hdr=$1; next }
NR == FNR { a[hdr]=$0; next }
{
    for ( hdrA in a ) {
        strA  = a[hdrA]
        lgthA = length(strA)
        for ( idxA=1; idxA<=(lgthA - wid + 1); idxA++ ) {
            substrA = substr(strA,idxA,wid)
            if ( index($0, substrA) ) {
                printf "[%s,%s]\n", hdrA, hdr
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
[1,1]
[1,2]
```

Comment: this was so helpfull but would this also work for big files? lets say 2 files with 10,000 or 50,000 sequences each? Thank you again.

Comment: @GSQ yes, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Dear @EdMorton I was "playing" with the script you kindly provided. However, I have a question that maybe you could help me to answer. When I run your script
```
awk -f file1 file2 > output_file
```
for some reason it does not recognize a match between this two sequences (next comment) but I know there is match "CACGACGGACGTTAGCACCCGCCGTGTGTC"
I already check the input files and they seem to be ok. Would it be possible that when running a lot of sequences, there could be false negatives in the output? 
In this case I ran 10000 sequences from file1 and 10000 from file2
Thank you!

Comment: (This comes from file1)

>8603
TAGCCCCGTTACATCTTCCGCGCAGGCCGACTCGACCAGTGAGCTATTACGCTTTCTTTAAATGATGGCTGCTTCTAAGCCAACATCCTGGCTGTCTGAGCCTTCCCACATCGTTTCCCACTTAGTAGTAATTTGGGACCTTAGCTGGCGGTCTGGGTTGTTTCCCTCTCCACGACGGACGTTAGCACCCGCCGTGTGTC

(This comes from file2)

>9977
CTTGGGGACCTTAGCTGTCGGTCAGGGTTGTTTCCCTCTTCACGACGGACGTTAGCACCCGCCGTGTGTCTGCCGACTAGTACTCCCGGGTATTCGGAGTTTGGTTAGGTTTGGTAAATCGGTGAGATCCCCTAGCCCATCCAGTGCTCTACCCCCCGGGGTATTCGGTCGACGCTCTACCTAAATAGATTTCGCGGAGA

Comment: The loop end condition was off by 1, I fixed it now.

Comment: Thank you @Ed Morton! Now its working perfectly!  :)

Comment: Hi @Ed Morton! I was wondering if you have any advice for the hamming distance post? :) thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is too lengthy and sounds too complicated and so would take too much time for me to look into, sorry.

Comment: Hi @Ed Morton, I was trying to obtain the coordinates of the matches and I was able to obtain the coordinate in the first match:
```

printf "%s_%s,position in file#1 at %s an file#2 %s, %s\n", hdrA, hdr, idxA++, , substrA
```

But how could I obtain the coordinate for the match in the second file?

Comment: If you have a new question then post that new question. [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged.